# Laravel auth:api middleware is not working on newly create route file

Tags: php, laravel, apache

I've a web app with Laravel 7. On that application I recently created a new api.php file under a folder named `api/v2` (`routes/api/v2/api.php`). The problem I'm facing is that on the newly created api.php file 'auth:api' middleware is not working.

I've checked the request headers and found out that `authorization` header is coming as empty for those routes. Everything works fine for older route file.

I've registered new api file inside RouteServiceProvider.php like this

```
Route::prefix('api/v2')
            ->middleware('api')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/api/v2/api.php'));
```

all routes are working fine without any issues except the auth problem. due to that I cannot call '$request->user()' method inside my controller.

PS: I'm using apache 2.4+

Anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Can you share your route file? Here is my attempt of doing the same that is working :

```
protected function mapAdminApiRoutes()
{
    Route::prefix('api/admin')
         ->middleware(['api','jwt.verify','role:admin'])
         ->namespace($this->namespace.'\Admin')
         ->group(base_path('routes/admin-api.php'));
}
```

Comment: I've multiple routes inside that routes file. and I don't want  to apply middleware to every route on the file. your way is giving auth middleware to all routes in that file

Comment: Then you should try Middleware groups in your route file : https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/middleware#middleware-groups:~:text=%5D%3B-,Middleware%20groups,-may%20be%20assigned

Group the routes you want to add the `auth` middleware together , or you can also go route wise

Comment: @HasilT If you want authentication you have to add authentication, Laravel can't guess that for you.